# MinGW-w64 pthread_cleanup_pop() error

Tags: c++, gcc, pthreads, mingw

when compiling a C++ program which contains a "call" to the `pthread_cleanup_pop(E)` macro, the following error is thrown by g++:

```
error: second operand to the conditional operator is of type 'void', but the third operand is neither a throw-expression nor of type 'void'
```

Now, the apparent problem here is that the macro above expands to
`(*pthread_getclean() = _pthread_cup.next, (E?_pthread_cup.func((pthread_once_t *)_pthread_cup.arg):0));}` where the second expression is a call to a function returning void, but the third expression is simply 0.

Althoug I get the basic issue here, I really don't see why the warning occurs in this particular use, as the "result" of the condition is not assigned to anything.

For the record: I compiled the C++ program using MinGW-w64 3.3.0 (GCC 4.9.2) both with and without -std=c++98. In both cases, the error occurs. If I compile the same code as a C program (both with or without -std=c99), there is no error.

Does anyone know how I could get rid of that error in C++, other than by editing pthread.h?

Many thanks in advance!

EDIT: Here is some example code for reference:

```
#include <pthread.h>

static int cancelled = 0;

static void test_thread_cleanup(void *_arg){
    cancelled = 1;
}

static void* test_thread(void *_arg){
    pthread_cleanup_push(&test_thread_cleanup, NULL);   // push cleanup handler on stack
    while (1){                                          // never left unless cancelled via pthread_cancel() from main()
        pthread_testcancel();                           // just test for pthread_cancel() having been called
    }
    pthread_cleanup_pop(1);                             // pop cleanup handler from stack

    return NULL;                                        // actually never reached
}

int main(void){
    pthread_t       th;

    pthread_create(&th, NULL, &test_thread, NULL);
    pthread_cancel(th);
    pthread_join(th, NULL);

    return cancelled;
}
```

Comment: How do *you* use the macro? What do you call it with? Please edit your question to show *your* code.

Comment: Compiles fine under a recent Debian (using gcc).

Comment: @alk: Thanks for the information. The problem is that MinGW-w64's particular implementation of pthreads for Windows includes a header file where the pop macro expands as mentioned above. I suppose that the macro expands differently on Linux (or other POSIX compliant) systems. Unfortunately, switching to Linux is no option for me here.